# What is lower-level on Windows: the C library or corresponding Win32 API functions?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've been wondering which is implemented in terms of which. My guess goes to eg `fopen` being implemented using `OpenFile`. From what I can tell, the Win32 API is more complete than the MSVC C library implementation, so my guess would make sense.

Is this correct, or is it the other way around?

Comment: There is no "C library" that's part of Windows. Every compiler ships its own. All C libraries may use the Windows API  (which *is* part of Windows), and the Windows API uses the Windows Kernel. You can also use the Windows Kernel directly, but it's undocumented and not stable (its API, that is, not the kernel itself).

Comment: Quite obviously, the C standard library is implemented on top of the Win32 API, not the other way around. You can deduct this from the presence of at least half a dozen different implementation of the C std library (some of which are open source and call Win32 functions).

Comment: *Parts* of the Windows Kernel are undocumented, and they're undocumented for a reason—you're not intended to be using them because they could change at any time! Other parts of the Windows Kernel, generally exported functions from `kernel32.dll`, are quite well documented and intended for general use. Damon's point is precisely correct—you could write your own C run-time library just like Microsoft did, using Windows functions. The Windows API *has* to be the lower-level because Windows is the operating system. Same in other environments: the CRT calls the OS, or lower-level system interrupts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Win32 is a "lower-level" API than the standard C-library ... basically the standard C-library on Windows is an abstraction of native Windows syscalls that allows certain standard operations to remain compatible across any series of platforms that support the C-standard library.  Each platform will have it's own implementation of the C-library based off internally native system calls.

Answer (score 2):

Well ultimately both will be implemented in terms of a kernel function that does call the driver which in turn does all the magic involved getting a file handle. If fopen does call OpenFile or if OpenFile calls fopen or neither of these call the other is something you 
cannot tell without looking at the source code (and different implementations might implement it differently...).

Comment: OpenFile is an old function nobody uses, I'm sure all CRT implementations use CreateFile

Comment: More specifically, `OpenFile` is a 16-bit Windows function; `CreateFile` has been overloaded to do many more things than creating a file in 32-bit Windows. But it's very likely that `CreateFile` *is* the kernel function (not to say it doesn't have lower-level, unexposed helper functions). It's a documented export from `kernel32.dll`.